# How do I get out of Google Sandbox

Tags: google-analytics, sandbox

I started my site in Januari of 2021 and after three months my visitors have decreased by 90%
It's a Wordpress site with a Yoast SEO plugin and connected to google analytics.

My stats have been suppressed in my opinion.
I am creating new content but Google is no hurry to index it and it feels like I'm under attack.
[My stats in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtgfS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure you are entering the sandbox. You can search Google by typing the following word.

```
site:mysite.com
```

If the result comes out, the situation is not bad, your site is indexed

The other is that you may be under attack. You can see malicious sites that give you backlinks through this website (Google Search Console does this too)

https://ahrefs.com/backlink-checker